# prevent empty document from being saved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a schema setup using Mongoose with three fields. Not one of them is required but I want to ensure that at least one of the three fields is populated to prevent empty documents from being saved (ideally actually I want to ensure that at least the `first` or `second` field is populated). What's the best way to do this? [`pre('save')`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) looks like an option but thought there should be a built in way to do this.

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
  first: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  second: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  third: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

var My = mongoose.model('My', mySchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have either `pre('save')` as you mentioned or a `validation` on one field to check this condition as given below.

```
var validateLocalStrategyProperty = function(property) {
    return this.first || this.second || this.third);
};

var mySchema = new Schema({
  first: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill at least one field']
  },
  second: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  third: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

var My = mongoose.model('My', mySchema);
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what is best practice?

Comment: You can go with the validation as it gives more control over each field

Comment: validation checks every time you save a document, .pre() only does it for that specific query.

Answer (score 0):

Pre method is best for this kind of use case.

```
mySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var self = this;
  if(self.first || self.second || self.third) {
    next();
  } else {
      next(new Error('At leat one of the filed should be there'))
    } 
}
```

One more option you have introduced a middleware that will validate your request and call the next function in route.

Comment: NEVER do things only on the client side, always check stuff in the server, as client side can be exploit!!!

Comment: Yes you are right writing middleware function is the best thing in this case. Avoid client side handling

Comment: I always do both, to avoid waiting for response from server, but never only on client.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a default value for the field which will be used when the field input is empty.

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
first: {
  type: String,
  trim: true,
  default: 'your string or something'
},
second: {
  type: String,
  trim: true,
  default: 'your string or something'
},
third: {
  type: Number,
  min: 1
}
}, {
timestamps: true
});

var My = mongoose.model('My', mySchema);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want it to save at all if both `first` and `second` are empty.

Comment: Okay then you can use the validate option as mentioned in Aruna's answer